# If a row in a column matches a row in another column, paste a value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup, vba

I've been very frustrated trying to figure this out.  I have an excel file like this:

```
Col  Col2     Col3     Col4    Col5
gene5 6 (empty column) gene1 this_is_gene1
gene1 4 (empty column) gene2 this_is_gene2
gene3 4 (empty column) gene3 this_is_gene3
gene2 3 (empty column) gene4 this_is_gene4
gene4 3 (empty column) gene5 this_is_gene5
gene5 3 (empty column) gene6 this_is_gene6
```

If any value in column 1 is present in column 4, I want it to then paste the information from column 5 into Column 3, like the following:

```
Col  Col2     Col3     Col4    Col5
gene5 6 this_is_gene6 gene1 this_is_gene1
gene1 4 this_is_gene4 gene2 this_is_gene2
gene3 4 this_is_gene4 gene3 this_is_gene3
gene2 3 this_is_gene3 gene4 this_is_gene4
gene4 3 this_is_gene4 gene5 this_is_gene5
gene5 3 this_is_gene5 gene6 this_is_gene6
```

Any help?  I've played around with =VLOOKUP, but it seems like that only works on a static value (instead of values within a whole column.)

Comment: Sometimes your lookup is col1 in col4 (return col5) and other times it is "gene"&col2 lookup in col4 (return col5).

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP should work for you, just tested it: Insert into your empty column `=VLOOKUP(A2; D2:E2; 2; FALSE)` assuming your table starts in cell A1 and has Col, Col2 etc as headers.

Answer (score 0):

The last two lines in your expected results do not match previous ones. Sometimes your lookup is col1 in col4 (return col5) and other times it is "gene"&col2 lookup in col4 (return col5).

```
'either,
=VLOOKUP("gene"&B2, D:E, 2, FALSE)
'or,
=VLOOKUP(A2, D:E, 2, FALSE)
```

[image]